# Hibernate mutual one-to-one relation

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have two classes Hotsheet and Invoice and one-to-one relation between them. I need to have a property in both classes which will link to each other. Here's my xml mapping of Invoice class.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="...Invoice" table="invoices">
    <id name="invoiceId" column="INVOICE_ID"/>

    ...

    <many-to-one
            name="hotsheet"
            column="HOTSHEET">
    </many-to-one>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Invoice has a foreign key that links to its Hotsheet and I also need a property in Hotsheet which will have its Invoice. If Hotsheet could have few invoices I would map it this way:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="package.Hotsheet" table="hotsheets">
    <id name="hotsheetId" column="HOTSHEET_ID"/>

    ...

    <bag name="invoices">
        <key column="HOTSHEET"/>
        <one-to-many class="...Invoice"/>
    </bag>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But this was, Hotsheet will have a list which will always contain only one Invoice, while I need a property with Invoice, not list with one Invoice.

Comment: Please be more relevant and describe in more details what you are expecing? What is wrong with one-to-one mapping?

Comment: I am expecting to create one to one relation between two objects. I know how to do it for many to one relation which will give me list of Invoices. But this has to be one to one, can you show me an example how map one to one relation for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#assoc-bidirectional-121) for **one-to-one** mapping in Hibernate. So you hbm files may be as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="...Invoice" table="invoices">
  <id name="invoiceId" column="INVOICE_ID"/>

  ...

  <many-to-one name="hotsheet" class="package.Hotsheet" column="INVOICE_HOTSHEET"  not-null="true" cascade="all" unique="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="package.Hotsheet" table="hotsheets">
  <id name="hotsheetId" column="HOTSHEET_ID"/>

  ...
  <one-to-one name="invoice" 
    property-ref="hotsheet"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Note that to create the *one-to-one* relationship we use the *many-to-one* with constraint **unique** set to true for the column `INVOICE_HOTSHEET`.

BR.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed and couldn't find it in the internet. property-ref attribute in ono-to-one helped me.